# java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #8 bootstrap method

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I am facing the following error in Android Studio:

**Logcat:**

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #8 bootstrap method

    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**Build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.easytaxi"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0')
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
        implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:3.1.0'
        implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    
    }
```

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
    
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: Hi There. Post actually code where this issue is coming. That would help people debug the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `build.gradle`

```html
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has saved my lot of time.